# how can i create this specific text file using python? (details down below)

Tags: python, file, text

I want a text file that has every variation of xxxxx-xxxxx (x is a number)
so I want to create a text file that goes
00000-00000
00000-00001
00000-00002
00000-00003
etc...
how can I do that with python?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a very easy task, but since it's going to create a file that is 120 gigabytes, I"m pretty sure this is not really what you need.  The easy way is just to have two nested loops with range(100000).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use .zfill(n) if you want to append "n" zeros before some integers. So, if you have i = 1 but you want to print it like 00001, you can you the following code:

```
print(str(i).zfill(5))
```

And as to your question, the solution is:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:

    for i in range(100000):
        for j in range(100000):
            my_str = str(i).zfill(5) + "-" + str(j).zfill(5) + "\n"
            f.write(my_str)

    f.close()
```

Note: This will take a while to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a nested loop like this:

```
pattern = '00000-00000'
stack = []

for i in range(100000):
    for j in range(100000):
        num = pattern[:5-len(str(i))]+str(i) + pattern[5] + pattern[6:-len(str(j))]+str(j)
        stack.append(num)
```

***Just don't run this code. It will break your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
lst = []

s = '0000000000'

for a in range(10000):
    l = list(s + str(a))[-10:]
    l.insert(4,'-')
    lst.append(''.join(l)+'\n')


with open('name.txt','w') as file:
    file.writelines(lst)
```